# Check if user input number is float with MARS system-calls

Tags: assembly, floating-point, integer, mips, mars-simulator

I'm doing a program in MIPS Assembly (using MARS 4_5) that has to be able to only read positive integers for my computer architecture class. My program should display a error message if the user's input is negative or has decimal places but I don't know how to do it. I mean, I know how to display the error message, I have done it already to negative (and 0) numbers, just not how to tell the program "If the input is a float number, then...".

Could anyone help me? Thank you so much.

For negative numbers I did this (among the rest of the program, of course):

```
blez $t0, error
```

```
error:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str9 #error message
    syscall
```

Comment: Read char by char. Verify it only has 0-9 in it. Done.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? Can you read a character? Can you do comparisons?

Comment: I don't know how to read the user's input characters and I only know how to compare by using the greater than, less than, etc commands. /:

Comment: Yes, greater than and less than is fine. To read chars use syscall number 12.

Comment: And to read a character should I use the .byte command on data? How should I store it? Using ' '?

Comment: You do not need anything in data, because the character is returned in `$v0`. You can just use that in the comparisons directly.

Comment: Would you be able to help me more directly? I saw in your account you are able to help using the libera chat, can I message you there? No problem if not, you were already a big help.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). I think Jester is trying to get you to [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) that you can make concrete progress on. If you're not sure where to begin, break the problem down further until you can. Can you read a sequence of characters in from the user? Can you loop over that string and print each character? Now, can you write a condition to test whether a character is a digit?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't want to spam the comments, that's why I was looking for a different way to ask everything away while I try different things. For now, I've been able to do a program that reads the character but only allows the user to write one number and then compare it to a number and link to a label accordingly. That last part has problems. But to reply to your questions, I don't I can do the loop since I don't know how to do the loop duration for the lenght of the user's input. And I can't write a condition to test whether a character is a digit. Once again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Try working out these issues in C or other programming language.  The underlying concept here is manipulating bytes of user input, which can be done in any language. You don't have to think in assembly to write a loop or and if-then statement.  When you do know what you want the program to do, getting that working in assembly language will be easier.  The idea is to separate the algorithm development from assembly translation.  That way you can ask specific questions about the algorithm needed, or specific questions about coding something in MIPS instead of this overly general question.

Comment: If you use the read-integer system call, I was going to say maybe MARS would leave the rest of the input line waiting to be read with read_char or read_string where you could check for a `'.'`.  But if there isn't one, that would presumably block until the user actually presses return again, and there isn't a non-blocking way to check if there's unread input in the buffer.  (If there even is a buffer.)  So yeah, probably have to read a string and convert it to an integer manually (then check what's next).

Comment: Or read_float and check if the number is an exact integer, but rounding error could round 1234567891234.01 to a whole number, and rounding to integer is non-trivial for numbers that might be larger than a 32-bit integer; you can't just convert to integer and back.